# Do Microsoft Wopi support duplicate file names in a container (folder)?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-wopi

Our company is currently implementing a WOPI server. Does Microsoft Wopi (Word) support duplicate file names in a container (folder)?

Our document management system supports duplicated filenames in a folder. If yes, we will try to implement it. Otherwise, we have to rethink.

Comment: I changed the word "fine" in your question and its title to "file." This is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question may be judged to be off-topic and closed without answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I believe this has to do with the parameters of the operating system rather than the program.

Answer (score 0):

WOPI methods like [`GetFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/getfile) and [`PutFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/putfile) use a parameter [`file_id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/concepts#file-id) which is a string that uniquely identifies a file.
If your DMS supports duplicate filenames, don't use them as the `file_id` parameter for WOPI. You surely have a different (and unique) parameter at your disposal that you can utilize.